# How do I take the values of one record in a table and split it into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which contain the following fields I need to use:

- Master Data: Master_ID (PK)
- Item Data: Crate_ID, Master_ID (FK), Item_Type_ID, Item_Type_Description, Item_Date

The Item_Type_ID has several different numerical values, i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ... 100 ... etc.
Each numerical value represents a type, i.e. Veggie, Fruit, Grains, Meat, etc.

The Item_Type_Description are things like: Fruit, Veggies, Grains, Meat, etc.

The Item_Date is a single date that identifies when that particular item (based upon Item_ID) was added to the Crate.

Note that there can only ever be one unique Item_Type_ID per Master_ID. Meaning, Item_Type_ID '10' can only ever be related to Master_ID '1234' once. An Item_Type_ID can be related to many different Master_IDs, but each of those Master_IDs, it can only be related once.

The issue I am having is that I can get the combined results, but for each Item_Type_ID, a distinct record/row is being created.

Here is the code I have generated thus far, which is giving me the incorrect Results:

```
USE Shipping
GO

BEGIN



SELECT
    vmi.master_id
    ,CASE
        WHEN vid.item_type_id = 10 THEN vid_item_date
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Fruit_Item_Date'
    ,CASE
        WHEN vid.item_type_id = 20 THEN vid_item_date
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Veggie_Item_Date'
    ,CASE
        WHEN vid.item_type_id = 30 THEN vid_item_date
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Grains_Item_Date'
    ,CASE
        WHEN vid.item_type_id = 40 THEN vid_item_date
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Meat_Item_Date'

FROM v_master_data vmi
LEFT JOIN v_item_data vid ON vmi.master_id = vid.master_id

WHERE vid.item_type_id IN (10,20,30,40)


END
GO
```

Any input, pointers, assistance, direction, advice, is greatly appreciated.

Running SQL Server 2016, accessed via SQL Server Management Studio v18.

Comment: Sample data and desired results as text is more helpful than an image.   Also there is no v18.   Select @@version will tell you what version you are running.

Comment: At a quick glance, it seems you are looking for a PIVOT or even a conditional aggregation

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, my apologies, MS SQL Server 2016, running on MS SQL Server Management Studio v18.

Will edit my post to add text examples rather than images.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, questions asking us to recommend or find books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources (*point me in the direction to read some materials*) are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite I appreciate the link with the explanation. Interestingly, when I first read your response, my initial thought was: If we shouldn't upload images, then why is it given as an option? After reading the post, it was clear the OP's initial thought was right in line with mine, but the answer provided was very clear. Thank you again.

As far as asking for recommendations, I was only suggesting that if no one could/wanted to assist in providing an answer to the issue I am facing, then pointing me toward some insightful instruction would still be helpful. Appreciate your insight. :)

Comment: Images are available for use in demonstrating issues that cannot be explained any other way, such as presentation issues. There is nothing in code/errors/data that can't be posted in the form of text. The post I linked explains the many reasons to avoid using images. It should be pretty clear. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, it was very clear. Thanks for the reference! :-)

Comment: And yet you have still not edited your post to remove the images and replace them with the proper text. :-)

Comment: I am in the process of doing just that. While they appear to be easy to follow along in the editor window, the preview has the text all jumbled up and not easy to follow. Trying to figure out how to make it legible. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will give you a little nudge

**PIVOT**

```
Select Master_ID
      ,Fruit_Date  = [10]
      ,Veggie_Date = [20]
      ,Grains_Date = [30]
      ,Meat_Date   = [40]
 From  (
        Select Master_ID
              ,Item_Type_ID
              ,Item_Date
         From  YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Item_Date) for Item_Type_ID in ( [10],[20],[30],[40] ) ) pvt
```

**Conditional Aggregation**

```
Select Master_ID
      ,Fruit_Date  = max( case when Iten_Type_ID =10 then Item_Date end)
      ,Veggie_Date = max( case when Iten_Type_ID =20 then Item_Date end)
      ,Grains_Date = max( case when Iten_Type_ID =30 then Item_Date end)
      ,Meat_Date   = max( case when Iten_Type_ID =40 then Item_Date end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Master_ID
```

A conditional aggregation offers a bit more flexibility and is often more performant.

Comment: John, thank you so much for your assistance. That is what I was looking for. I adapted your responses to my full scenario and each of them provided the desired results. I do have to say, as you pointed out, that the conditional aggregation does offer a bit more flexibility and provided the results much quicker. Thank you again!